# import from zlib in Vite+React app gives an error

Tags: reactjs, vite, zlib

I'm trying to import **gunzipSync** from zlib** package on our **react+vite** app. However, I get following error message when importing anything from the package:

```
✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "./zlib_bindings"

    node_modules/zlib/lib/zlib.js:1:25:
      1 │ module.exports = require('./zlib_bindings');
        ╵                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

2:41:58 PM [vite] error while updating dependencies:
Error: Build failed with 1 error:
node_modules/zlib/lib/zlib.js:1:25: ERROR: Could not resolve "./zlib_bindings"
    at failureErrorWithLog (/home/jukka/documents/NavigilService/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1649:15)
    at /home/jukka/documents/NavigilService/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1058:25
    at /home/jukka/documents/NavigilService/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1525:9
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

On our old version of the app that used **create-react-app** it didn't have any problems importing anything from **zlib**. I assume it is due to **webpack** knowing how to handle zlib since Vite doesn't use webpack.

Does anyone have any idea how to get **zlib** working under Vite+React?

Comment: You can't import `zlib`, a native package, in frontend JavaScript. I don't know how it could have possibly worked with CRA/Webpack.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to use **pako** package for unzipping the gzipped data from fetch. In case someone has the same problem, here is how I did it:

```
import pako from 'pako';

const checkUnZip = async data => {
  try {
    if (data.body.isBase64Encoded) {
      let strData = atob(data.body.zipped);
      // Convert binary string to character-number array
      const charData = strData.split('').map(x => x.charCodeAt(0));
      // Turn number array into byte-array
      const binData = new Uint8Array(charData);
      // Pako magic
      const pakoData = pako.inflate(binData);
      // Convert gunzipped byteArray back to ascii string:
      strData = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(pakoData));
      const unzippedData = { statusCode: data.body.statusCode, body: JSON.parse(strData) };
      return unzippedData;
    }
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    return data;
  }
};

// in middle of your fetch-logic/middleware/whatever
...
    data = await response.json();
    data = await checkUnZip(data);
// continue with your operation
...
```

This didn't solve the problem of importing **zlib**, so I am not marking this as a solution for my question.